How to view Closed Captions as Transcripts of videos stored in Google Drive?
I have a video of a Zoom meeting that was shared via Google Drive.  If I click the CC button, I can see the machine-generated Closed Captioning, which I'm assuming Google has added automatically.  Is there any way to view the whole transcript of that CC data?  It would make it much easier to find a relevant part of the meeting.

Google has a help document regarding Drive video file captions that could be helpful: Add caption tracks to your video files

Based on the helpful pointer from @Blindspots, I was able to do this as follows:

From the Google Drive folder containing the video file, click the More Actions (⠇ menu) for the file, then choose File Information > Manage Caption Tracks.

The video opens in a new tab, with the Manage Caption Tracks tool open.  One track was listed, "English (detected) Auto-generated."  Click the More Actions (⠇ menu) for the Caption track, and choose Download.


This produced a .vtt file, which is plain text of the captions, with time stamps included.  This is perfect for finding the relevant part of the meeting.
Note: the linked Google Drive Help doc indicates that the Manage Caption Tracks tools should also be selectable while watching the video, but I was not able to find it as documented.  Using the context menu in the Drive folder view is an easy work-around.
